# How to prevent Firefox from asking if we really want to quit?

Tags: macos, firefox, reboot

When I close my MacMini. A popup is displayed by Firefox "You are about to close 15 tabs, are you sure?..."

[image: firef]

How to avoid having this and shutting down the computer without any confirmation? Thanks.

I have this in the preferences (FR):

[image]

Comment: Huh.  Interesting that Mac Firefox is missing the checkbox offered by windows.  Not having a Mac, I'll suggest you try going to `about:config`, typing "warnon" (one word) into the search box, and seeing if there are any settings that might help.

Comment: I'd rather leave that to a mac user (or you yourself) to do.  Given that Mac Firefox lacks the checkbox, I'm not sure it even has the setting I'm referring to.  Also, I really don't know which setting to change; this is more of a guess than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

- Click the three-bars top-right icon
- Choose Options
- In the General section, uncheck "Warn you when closing multiple tabs".

---

[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't have this option. I had to do via `about:config`. Can you provide a screenshot? In the "tab" section, I only see tree options.

Comment: Added the screenshot. Are you on Firefox version 73?

Comment: Yes, 73.0. I only have three options. Not four or more like you. I have added a screenshot too.

Comment: I think Firefox should be uniform across platforms, so this might be a remnant from a previous installation. You could try to uninstall Firefox and scrub all its folders (saving bookmarks), then reinstall. I also wonder if it's possible there is a difference between the French and English versions.

Comment: Ok I wil accept the answer because it should ok for most users, it not they can use the anwser provided in one of the comments. "about:config" -> "warnon".

Comment: For me with the latest English version of Firefox, this setting is missing.

Comment: @Brian: Not for me.